# Estimator for the correlation coefficient

Tags: correlation, hypothesis-testing, parameter-estimation

My question is related to the correlation between random variables X and Y, where $(X,Y)$ is bivariate normal. My understanding is as follows.

The correlation coefficient is $\rho=\dfrac{\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(X)\operatorname{Var}(Y)}}$.

Taking samples from $(X,Y)$, the sample correlation coefficient is $R=\dfrac{\sum(X_i-\overline{X})(Y_i-\overline{Y})}{\sqrt{\sum(X_i-\overline{X})^2\sum(Y_i-\overline{Y})^2}}$.

My question is:

Is $R$ an unbiased estimator for $\rho$? If yes, can you guide me to a proof?

Remark: Following the advice in the comment, I [split the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1861866/hypothesis-testing-for-the-correlation-coefficient) into two.

Comment: This is a set of related questions that should br separate. Please pick one to keep, and ask the other separately. Keeping the background similar and linking to the other is a good idea though.

Comment: please [merge](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) your accounts